# A question voted to be off-topic and better suited to writers.SE has not been migrated

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, migration

[When should one use a section sign](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38258/when-should-one-use-a-section-sign) (the link is only for 10k users) has been voted as off-topic and better suited to writers.SE by 5 users, but the question was simply closed.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39343/is-it-always-ok-to-use-the-verb-to-say-after-a-question has been voted to be migrated from all the users who voted to close it, but the question is still not migrated. This time I have been sure to check twice how many users voted to migrated, and before I voted too, they were 4.

Did I miss a new feature announcement, or is this the way it should work since the beginning?
Is there a bug, or did not all the voters vote to migrate?

Comment: That's very odd that it happened a second time—I've updated my answer in response. @simchona No such process exists, although it's been proposed and rejected on MSO before.

Comment: @waiwai933 I am just sorry I didn't think of taking a screenshot; as justification, I can say I was really thinking the question was going to be migrated, but I keep hitting the wall with my head all the times I think of the opportunity I missed. Who knows when another question will be voted to be migrated from 5 users out of 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[symbol](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbol) and [word-usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage) do not exist on Writers.

To prevent a back-door for creating tags, when a question is voted to be migrated, the tags are checked on the destination site.  Any tags that don't exist will be stripped from the question.  If that process leaves a question without any tags, then it will simply be closed as off-topic.  Mods can override this, notice how [this question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3740/is-it-always-ok-to-use-the-verb-to-say-after-a-question) is tagged with [untagged].

(Not sure I understand the migration on the "to say" question, but that's a different matter I guess.)

Comment: That explains why a recent question has been successfully migrated without a vote from moderators, and the questions I am referring to were not migrated. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, only a dev can view the specific close votes, so I can't speak as to this situation precisely, but I do want to mention two things:

- Is it possible that some of the close voters selected *off topic* but not *belongs on writers*? That would show up as 4 votes to close as off topic, which you have to click through to get to the subselection and might be what you saw.
- The user has [reposted the question on Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3644/when-should-one-use-a-section-sign), which is why I've deleted the question and not migrated it.

About the second instance:

- Since you double-checked, and given the question, I'm 100% sure that the votes were migration votes, and the only other way a migration can be blocked is by a mod voting to close for a different reason. This didn't happen, so I've retagged your question [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) in the hope that it'll kick a dev into looking at this.
- I reopened and reclosed (with migration) the question, which seems to have worked. The [revision history](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/39343/revisions) is still there if anyone's interested.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, fewer than three of the five people who voted to close that question believed it belongs on Writers. Thus, it was simply closed instead of being migrated.

Comment: Strange, I was sure that all the users selected the checkbox to migrate it to writers.SE; I checked that before to select it myself. If I saw that just 2 users suggested to migrate the question to writers.SE, I would have not suggested the migration. It is probable that not all the users voted to migrate, if a bug didn't kick in.

Comment: I know I selected to migrate. Is it possible for a mod to still do so?