# Should those 10K who link to deleted questions give a warning?

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1764/a-question-voted-to-be-off-topic-and-better-suited-to-writers-se-has-not-been-mig) (and I have seen this issue other time) the poster links to [other question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38258/when-should-one-use-a-section-sign) that can be seen only by a member with at least 10K reputation.
Shouldn't the poster give a warning (or something else), because otherwise those under 10k  click on it and don't see anything-wasted time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could have given a warning, if the question were already closed when I wrote the question on the meta site, but I wrote the question the day before the referred question was deleted. `:-)`

I normally leave a comment reporting when a link is useful only for 10k user, and I think that is a courtesy to leave such comments, except in the case the question is clearly about something only 10k user can use. (If, for example, the question is about the moderator tools, then commenting that https://english.stackexchange.com/tools is a link accessible to 10k users seems superfluous.)

If you see a question on meta that is referring to a deleted question, feel free to propose an edit for that meta question.